# How to show annotations for methods and vars in UML

Tags: uml

Lets assume i have the following method:

```
[superannotation]
fun ultimateMethod([anotherannotation] bla: String) {
  //the ultimate code
}
```

i would than create something similar to that:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UML does not define how to translate an annotation to a UML concept, but yes, a stereotype seems the most logical equivalent, although an annotation can have parameters and a stereotype cannot.

The UML 2.5.1 specification section 12.3.3.4 describes how to define your own stereotype in UML and section 12.3.3.6 describes how to extend a metaclass to use the stereotype. In your case:

[image: stereotypedefinition]

Comment: Actually a Stereotype can have properties (unfortunately still known as "tagged values"). I would consider these to be corresponding to parameters of annotations.